# Virtual machine - Azure, setting up web server

Tags: windows, web-services, azure, virtual-machine

I have installed a windows server 2012 virtual machine. However it seems as though IIS is not set up, and it is not set up for the web, hence when I type the URL into the address bar, I get nothing back.

How can I make the server web ready?

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  If you want a website, use a Cloud Service with a web role or an Azure Website.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that by default a Virtual Machine is created with only the RDP port open in the Windows Azure firewall.

If you want to be able to browse to your machine from outside Azure you have to open up the firewall by going to the machine in the Windows Azure Management Portal, switching to the endpoints tab and adding a TCP endpoint with public  port 80 and private port 80 (you may consider opening 443 as well if you need SSL).

This will allow traffic through the firewall onto your machine on the ports that you open and, if you have configured IIS, access to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

All you get is a virtual machine in IaaS scenario and it's up to you as to how you wish to use it. May I suggest that you download the **Azure Readiness Content** (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396) and there's a hands-on lab about Windows Azure Virtual Machines (It's called "**IntroToWindowsAzureVirtualMachines**"). This lab will guide your through that process.